# Significant lower accuracy when using empty ImageDataGenerator in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a Convolutional Network to classify the CIFAR-100 dataset and I have run into an unsual problem. Now, I might be making an obvious mistake, but since I am very new to this field I cannot seem to find it.

The network was working fine until I tried to introduce an ImageDataGenerator to augment the input data. I noticed a large diffrence in accuracies so I tried to use an empty ImageDataGenerator. The problem remained.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
)

datagen.fit(train_images)

history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=128), steps_per_epoch=train_images.shape[0]//128, epochs=250, 
                   validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

The code above gives the following result:

```
Epoch 1/250
390/390 [==============================] - 29s 75ms/step - loss: 4.6235 - accuracy: 0.0040 - val_loss: 4.7914 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

While this one, without using a generator, gives a much better one:

```
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=128, epochs=250, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

```
Epoch 1/250
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 69ms/step - loss: 4.6176 - accuracy: 0.0179 - val_loss: 4.7109 - val_accuracy: 0.0095
```

Shouldn't these two methods give the same result since the ImageDataGenerator does not do anything to the input?

Comment: what is `train_images` ? numpy matrix? list of images?

Comment: These comparisons make no sense due to random weight initialization

Comment: You will need to show more training results before we can tell you much of anything.  A single epoch provides almost no information. If there is really a problem over a longer training period, it would be useful to see how the ImageDataGenerator is initialized.  Additionally, note that if you're in TF2+, then fit_generator is deprecated. You can just use fit as it will accept generators.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I dont feel is a good idea to use the first epoch as a sign of how well your CNN works. You should let it converge to see if there is a true performance difference.

Also, there is a difference in using the raw data in compare with ImageDataGenerator. ImageDataGenerator creates data augmentation during train using different values. I think is not a good idea using default values on it though doing it you just duplicate data. Try, at least, to change some values as width_shift_range, height_shift_range and rotation_range.

Comment: I understand, while I did only show the first epoch, the raw data model trained a lot better than the one with ImageDataGenerator. My point was to show that, even though the ImageDataGenerator is not chaning the input, the results are vastly different.

Comment: Yep, true, I think I should change my answer, I though you asked something different. The thing is that even using same data, the performance tend to variate because there are some other factors to take into account such as the random seed to generate weights. Also (a bit of speculation here), using the ImageDataGenerator may variate the order on reading the images. WIsh it can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I think that shuffle might be set to True by default, altough that does not appear to change the result much. I will have to experiment.